# cannot use (type string) as type func() in assignment

Tags: go

I have a yaml file in the following format:

```
checks:
      CheckIPReachability:
        args:
          ip: 127.0.0.1
          port: 22
      xyz_check:
        args:
          xyz_arg: xxx
          xyz_arg1: yy
```

I plan to accept this type of input from user and call CheckIPReachability or any xyz func and send args to it. Individual functions would extract the args and perform the task.

I tried to do this,

```
m := make(map[string]func())

for prp, val := range checks {
  m["func"] = prp.(func())
  m["func"]()
}
```

which fails with:

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not func()

so prp is "CheckIPReachability" and I am unable to call that as a function, inspite of converting it to a func.

I also want to know whats the best possible way here (interfaces ?). Adding a switch case doesnt look right.

https://play.golang.org/p/B9w6p4MCI7V

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to call as a function? What is `checks`?

Comment: That's all interesting, but doesn't answer the question. What are you trying to call as a function? What is the type of `checks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a string to a function. You may try using some kind of mapping, e.g.:

```
checkers := map[string]func() {
    "CheckIPReachability": checkIPReachability,
}

checkers[name]()
```

If you need to pass the arguments, the function would be like:

```
func checkIPReachability(args []interface{}) {
    // convert args and check the IPs
}

checkers := map[string]func([]interface{}) {
    "CheckIPReachability": "checkIPReachability",
}
```

If you want to allow the users of your framework to add their own checker, you can export that as a function `RegisterChecker(string, func(interface{}))` or something similar.

A simpler alternative is a [`switch-case`](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/9) statement:

```
switch funcname {
    case "CheckIPReachability":
        // convert arguments and call the function
    case "OtherCheck":
        // same here
}
```

Comment: problem with this map is checkIPReachability is retrieved dynamically via yaml.

I had plans to give developers independently develop their functions and not touch the main code.. but as per your suggestion looks like we have to modify switch case everytime we write new function.. 
Thanks for your suggestion.. seems like no way around this.

Comment: If it's a framework, it may provide a way to expand that map with a `Register()` call. Updated the answer.

Comment: thank you.. The idea was our users would not have expertise on golang.. hence the yaml was suggested and under the hoods we perform the task for them.

Comment: There's definitely no simple way to make this user-expansible without having them write some code in Go.

Comment: ok understood..

Comment: Thanks bereal.. accepting your solution. I'll probably look at either the global map option or resort to switch case.